# PHP Codeigniter convert many IF's with regex DRY

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, dry

I'm building an application using CI latest. My problem is that i have a long list of regex like:

```
$regex1 = "/.../";
$regex2 = "/.../";
...
$regexn = "/.../";
```

And i need to pass an if statement for every regex like this:

```
if(preg_match($regex1, $input)){
$data['result'] = $this->Model1->get_text();
}

if(preg_match($regex2, $input)){
$data['result'] = $this->Model2->get_text();
}
...
```

The thing works but i hate to see all the if's there. And my question is how can i shorten this in any way and make it more maintainable in CI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array to loop through each possibility, Although this example is dependant on the idea that your models are actually named `Model1`.. `Model2` (Sorry if that was there for just as an Example, otherwise replace the numbered keys to your model names, `ModelAdmin => $regex1` etc. )

```
$Regexes = array( 
          0 => $regex1,
          1 => $regex2,
          //etc
      );

foreach( $Regexes as $Key => $Regex ) {
   if( preg_match( $Regex, $input )) {
       $Model = "Model" . $Key;
       $data['result'][] = $this->$Model->get_text();
   }
}
```

Furthermore, added an `[]` at the end of `$data['result']`, otherwise it overwrite the previous 'result'

Comment: It works as expected but i forgot one thing. the get_text() method can be different. I'm thinking of placing in the array key a value like: Model_xxx:get_text() and split them with explode.

Comment: Or add another depth =) `"ModelName" => array( "regex" => $regex1, "method" => "get_text" );` then, `$this->$ModelName->{$Regex["method"]}();` and `preg_match( $Regex["regex"], ..`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) instead of if statements? It wouldn't be a huge difference, but switch is usually a better choice for cases where you have a lot of options.

For example:

```
switch $data['result'] {
    case (preg_match($regex1, $data['result']) ? true : false):
        $data['result'] = $this->Model1->get_text();
        break;
    case (preg_match($regex2, $data['result']) ? true : false):
        $data['result'] = $this->Model2->get_text();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single [**preg_filter function call**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php):

```
// array of regex patterns
$patterns = array($regex1, $regex2, $regex3);
// preg_filter will return null (supplied as 2nd argument) if all REs fail to match
if ( preg_filter($patterns, null, $input) )
    $data['result'] = $this->$Model->get_text();
```